# My question is about SQL, using a TOP function inside a sub-query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Overall what I'm trying to achieve is a query that shows the most ordered item from a customer in a database. To achieve this I've tried making a query showing how many times a customer has ordered an item, and now I am trying to create a sub-query in it using TOP1 to discern the most bought items.

[image: Here is a picture of my relationships]

[image: Here is the results of the first query]

With the SQL from the first query (looking weird because I made it with the Access automatic creator):

```
SELECT
    Customers.CustomerFirstName,
    Customers.CustomerLastName,
    Products.ProductName,
    COUNT(SalesQuantity.ProductCode) AS CountOfProductCode
FROM (Employees
INNER JOIN (Customers
    INNER JOIN Sales
        ON Customers.CustomerCode = Sales.CustomerCode)
    ON Employees.EmployeeCode = Sales.EmployeeCode) 
        INNER JOIN (Products
            INNER JOIN SalesQuantity
                ON Products.ProductCode = SalesQuantity.ProductCode)
            ON Sales.SalesCode = SalesQuantity.SalesCode
GROUP BY
    Customers.CustomerFirstName,
    Customers.CustomerLastName,
    Products.ProductName
ORDER BY
    COUNT(SalesQuantity.ProductCode) DESC;
```

I have tried putting in a subquery after FROM line:

```
(SELECT TOP1 CountOfProduct(s)
FROM (.....)
ORDER by Count(SalesQuantity.ProductCode) DESC)
```

I'm just not sure what to put in for the "from"-every other tutorial has the data from an already created table, however this is from a query that is being made at the same time. Just messing around I've put "FROM" and then listed every table, as well as

```
FROM Count(SalesQuantity.ProductCode)
```

just because I've seen that in the order by from the other code, and assume that the query is discerning from this count. Both tries have ended with an error in the syntax of the "FROM" line.

I'm new to SQL so sorry if it's blatantly obvious, but any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If you just replace the outermost `SELECT` with `SELECT TOP 1` what happens?  Does it work?

Comment: Data should be posted as text in query so readers can copy/paste into a table for testing.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen no it doesn't, but thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want the most purchased product for each customer.

So, begin by building aggregate query that counts product purchases by customer (appears to be done in the posted image). Including customer ID in the query would simplify the next step which is to build another query with TOP N nested query.

Part of what complicates this is unique record identifier is lost because of aggregation. Have to use other fields from the aggregate query to provide unique identifier. Consider:

```
SELECT * FROM Query1 WHERE CustomerID & ProductName IN 
    (SELECT TOP 1 CustomerID & ProductName FROM Query1 AS Dupe 
     WHERE Dupe.CustomerID = Query1.CustomerID 
     ORDER BY Dupe.CustomerID, Dupe.CountOfProductCode DESC);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, I just needed some clarification- so I placed the code in a new Query and substituted my values inside. When attempting to run, dialog boxes appeared asking for a parameter value on CustomerID as well as Dupe Count of Product.  I haven't misspelt anything, so I don't understand why it would ask for this. Maybe its because I'm new to SQL, but I'm assuming that when you select the CustomerID and ProductName from the first query and classify it as Dupe, should I see this duplicate table of values saved anywhere? Thanks

Comment: I built a table that looks like dataset in image with addition of CustomerID field. The query works for me without popups. Did you modify Query1 to include CustomerID? What is your field name? Looks like I misspelled CountOfProduct - you have CountOfProductCode. Corrected my answer to show that name.

Comment: No, there is no Dupe table saved anywhere - it lives only within the query. Is your customer identifier field CustomerCode?

Comment: Thank you so much, I have it working now and yeah it was my mispelling :D

Answer (score 0):

> Overall what I'm trying to achieve is a query that shows the most ordered item from a customer in a database.

This answers your question.  It does not modify your query which is only tangentially related.

```
SELECT s.CustomerCode, sq.ProductCode, SUM(sq.quantity) as qty
FROM Sales as s INNER JOIN
     SalesQuantity as sq
     ON s.SalesCode = sq.SalesCode
GROUP BY s.CustomerCode, sq.ProductCode;
```

To get the most ordered items, you can use this twice:

```
SELECT s.CustomerCode, sq.ProductCode, SUM(sq.quantity) as qty
FROM Sales as s INNER JOIN
     SalesQuantity as sq
     ON s.SalesCode = sq.SalesCode
GROUP BY s.CustomerCode, sq.ProductCode
HAVING sq.ProductCode IN (SELECT TOP 1 sq2.ProductCode
                          FROM Sales as s2 INNER JOIN
                               SalesQuantity as sq2
                               ON s2.SalesCode = sq2.SalesCode
                          WHERE s2.CustomerCode = s.CustomerCode
                          GROUP BY sq2.ProductCode
                         );
```

In almost any other database, this would be simpler, because you would be able to use window functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, it explains a fair amount :) - I was just wondering, when trying to run the second group of code to get most ordered items, I recieve an error saying ProductCode is not part of 'aggregate function' and after a google search I still don't fully understand it-could you please explain what the problem is, and a possible fix I can work on? Thanks

Comment: @MrYummy8626 . . . The problem was the table alias in the `GROUP BY`.  I fixed the code.